# Exponential of Liouville Numbers

Tags: diophantine-approximation, transcendental-number-theory, transcendence

By Mahler classification of Transcendental real numbers (into the sets of $S$-, $T$- and $U$-numbers), we know that

- Any Liouville number is a $U$-number.
- $\log \alpha$ is either an $S$- or a $T$-number, for any algebraic number
  $\alpha\not\in \{0, 1\}$.

Thus, $e^{\xi}$ is a transcendental number, for any Liouville number $\xi$ (otherwise, if $e^{\xi}=\alpha\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, then $\xi=\log \alpha$ belongs to either an $S$- or a $T$-number which contradicts the fact that $\xi$ is a Liouville number).

My question is:

**Question.** *For any Liouville number $\xi$, the number $e^{\xi}$ is a Liouville number?*

I don't think so, but I don't know how to construct a Liouville number $\xi$ for which $e^{\xi}$ is a Diophantine number.